# Is this dash correct?

Tags: punctuation, dashes

I’m hoping someone can give me some feedback/advice on the dash below.

> The site also supports a mobile
>   version that allows you to easily
>   check whether a book is in your
>   collection—a feature inspired after
>   purchasing already-owned books one too
>   many times.

I guess I could also split this into two sentences.

> The site also supports a mobile
>   version that allows you to easily
>   check whether a book is in your
>   collection.  This feature was inspired
>   after purchasing already-owned books
>   one too many times.

Is the first version is correct, and if so, is it preferable to the second?

[This link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114/when-to-use-a-semicolon-and-when-to-use-a-dash/2053#2053) makes me think it's correct, but I thought I'd ask the community; I always seem to get fantastic feedback here.

Comment: I would suggest just replacing the dash with a comma. Oh, and I think you mean *a mobile version **that** allows* rather than *a mobile version **which** allows*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first version is correct.  You've used a dash to separate the appositive from the main sentence, which is acceptable.  Usually, this is considered better than the second version; one independent clause is better than two, stylistically speaking.  I myself would probably have used a comma instead of a dash, since I think commas give a much nicer flow.

Comment: Andrew, is my understanding correct that an appositive can be offset with **either** a comma **or** a dash, and that a comma is usually only used for very small appositives, such as: "Andrew, a brilliant English teacher, will be at the party."  I opted for the dash above because I thought it was a bit much for a comma

Comment: Yes, that's the way of it; it can be either commas or dashes.  Dashes are more frequent when you're going for effect; it's almost like a quick drum roll before the punch line.  That's how I feel about them, anyway.

Comment: It's a matter of taste, to be sure, but I'm leaning toward the dash because this is catch copy. We're trumpeting a new feature here, we're excited, we've solved a user problem, so the urgency and fortississimo of the dash seem appropriate.