# Why a dash in this example?

Tags: punctuation, dashes

I am reading an article by Bill Keller (*The Times*). He wrote:

> Through the years, The New York Times’s coverage of the Roman Catholic Church and the Vatican has received sharp criticism from practicing Catholics — including the past eight years that Bill Keller has been the paper’s executive editor.

Why has he used a hyphen (-)?

Comment: Related: [When to use a semicolon and when to use a dash?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114/when-to-use-a-semicolon-and-when-to-use-a-dash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a hyphen, it's an n-dash, used to indicate that the following text is closely connected to the earlier text, and adds something that cannot be added to the sentence directly.

Look up "n-dash" for full details of its usage.

Comment: Usually written as "en dash."

Comment: Strictly speaking, he should really be using an em-dash and not an en-dash for this. The em-dash is longer.

Comment: I wouldn't use an m-dash, but that's largely personal preference, because using spaced n-dashes makes the text easier on the eye, and therefore easier to read.  Note that using an m-dash would be for personal preference, too -- neither usage is either wrong or more correct than the other.