# What is the correct punctuation for this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, dashes

> Yet I cannot remain in these moments for very long without being reminded of nature's harsh and unforgiving **side;  I** think about fording a raging glacial river in Denali National Park in Alaska and avoiding a bear as he ravages my two-week supply of food.

I am not sure what punctuation to use here.  My reasoning for currently using the semicolon is the rule of two related sentences.  Would a dash serve this thought better?

Comment: I don't think a dash would work at all well. A simple period would be best. But it looks like *writing advice* to me.

Comment: We have [a dedicated question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114/should-i-use-a-semicolon-or-a-dash-to-connect-two-closely-related-sentences) for choosing between a semicolon and a dash. Though as FumbleFingers points out, this is not a sentence, these are two sentences. There is no reason for anything but a period to be there.