# Punctuation to separate clauses: "What is X _ now that Y?"

Tags: punctuation, dependent-clause

In sentences like:

> What is your name _ now that you have changed it?
>
> Where do they live _ now that the coal industry has collapsed?
>
> Why are we still here _ now that the election is over?

is any punctuation needed in between the clauses?  The only options I can think of:

> 1) What is X now that Y?
>
> 2) What is X, now that Y?
>
> 3) What is X; now that Y?

Answer (score 2):

You don't absolutely need any punctuation at all, since the sentence is unambiguous as it stands.

It depends entirely on how you want it to be read, without a pause,  with a slight pause, or a longer pause. And this will depend on the extent to which you want the Y part to be regarded as integral to the main thought, and to what extent supplementary to it.

Comment: For an intended longer pause: "What is X -- now that Y?" (if you really wished to emphasize the Y part) or possibly "What is X ... now that Y?" (for a delayed afterthought).

Comment: @martinf I suppose you could use dots, but I would use a comma or a semi-colon.

Comment: A semicolon looks decidedly wrong here, for not one but two reasons: The second clause cannot stand on its own, and the question mark it ends in belongs to the first one. If you are considering a longer pause, an em dash is the way to go. See [Should I use a semicolon or a dash to connect two closely related sentences?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114/should-i-use-a-semicolon-or-a-dash-to-connect-two-closely-related-sentences)

Answer (score 2):

"What is your name" is the main clause. "Now that you've changed it" is the dependent clause. However, it is not a restrictive clause (the fact that it has been changed does not affect the understanding of the main clause). Because it is not a restrictive clause, you need a comma after the main clause. "What is your name, now that you've changed it. You can also take the second clause as an explanatory clause, the reason *why* the question is being asked, and explanatory clauses also get commas before them (admittedly, this last point is probably unorthodox, but I think it still holds true).

Either way, while the sentence reads fine without it, the "proper" method is to use a comma—well, proper according to the Chicago Manual of Style. There may be other style manuals that say different.