# should I use a colon or semicolon here?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, colons

My sentence (roughly—it's in a scientific document and i have simplified somewhat):

> It is more relevant to calculate A relative to B: although C filters
>   the observation, B describes the true information content.

Do you think I should replace the colon with a semicolon? I used a colon because the latter part of the sentence is an explanation of the first clause. Someone has suggested a semicolon instead.

Comment: Howo about a _since_ instead of either?

Comment: thanks for the comment, but I'm afraid that wouldn't work here: "since although"??

Comment: _Although C filters the observation, it is more relevant to calculate A relative to B since B describes the true information content_

Comment: @mplungjan yes that would be OK but it subtly changes the emphasis which does not fit so well in context. I see no reason to avoid punctuation: it is a perfectly legitimate part of a sentence!

Comment: Possibly legitimate but harder to read and absorb.  _It is more relevant to calculate A relative to B since B describes the true information content notwithstanding that C filters the observation_

Comment: Why the downvoting? Seems a bit mean... it was a genuine question that some folks were kind enough to answer.

Comment: Don't take it too seriously. Some people need to learn how to comment their downvoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a colon or a dash (not a hyphen). As you say yourself, with these you inform the reader that what follows is an explanation of what precedes. With a semicolon, the reader loses that information. See also [this related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/4015/300). The same reasoning applies here.

Comment: As an aside, very few people grok semicolons, so a rather useful rule of thumb is: if you're not sure if you should use a semicolon, then don't.

Comment: Yes I could use a dash. In fact I do use them quite a lot. But at least now one person agrees with me a colon is OK, I'll leave it as is!

Comment: Colon is completely wrong :) If you'd written (and I'm not claiming this is good English) "It is more relevant to calculate A relative to B, and here's why:" then the colon is fine. But you haven't given any signal that an explanation for why is imminent. I like @mplungjan's suggestion of since instead. I would actually reverse the order of two halves of the sentence then use a conjunction like "therefore".

Comment: @TheMathemagician the colon *is* the signal that an explanation for why is imminent. You do not need to precede every colon with a "here's why": it itself is a shorthand for just that.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Sure when it's clear that a list or explanation is coming, but here a colon seems unnatural and it's not at all obvious what's coming even after we've seen the colon. In any case I think reversing the sentence is better: [<--colon and you already know that I'm going to give an example of the reversed sentence] "Although C filters the observation, B describes the true information content, therefore it is more relevant to calculate A relative to B."

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually say they are two separate sentences and it ends with a period after `'... relative to B.'`; starting a new sentence with `'Although...'`.

Comment: Using a colon does not mean that they are not two separate sentences; rather the opposite. Using a period would completely get rid of the hint to the reader that the second sentence is an _explanation_ to the first.

Answer (score 0):

How about avoiding the punctuation; although valid, it blocks fluent reading — something I dislike (especially if the sentence can be restructured)

This works better for me but it changes the emphasis as you correctly observed

> Although C filters the observation, it is more relevant to calculate A relative to B since B describes the true information content

But this does not in my opinion change the emphasis but does use a longer, possibly stuffy word - perhaps although could take its place?

> It is more relevant to calculate A relative to B since B describes the true information content notwithstanding that C filters the observation.

Comment: Well, I would be happy enough with "It is more relevant to calculate A relative to B since B describes the true information content even though it is C that filters the observation". Thanks for taking the time to answer