# Use of semi colon or colon?

Tags: grammar, lists, semicolons, colons

So I want to make a sentence presenting a list first and asking a question about it at the end. But I am confused whether semi colon should be used or colon should be used. I am of the view that colon should be used but it's better to ask than to make an error.

Here's the sentence

> Ice-cream, candy and pie: too sweet to go together, aren't they?

Comment: A semicolon makes no sense at all. A colon is the clueless man's choice. You are looking for an [em dash](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114/should-i-use-a-semicolon-or-a-dash-to-connect-two-closely-related-sentences). (Never a hyphen, mind.)

Comment: Well, it isn't a sentence anyway.

Comment: @IsabelArcher clause may be?

Comment: @RegDwigнt dashes are used to write afterthoughts, I read somewhere, but there's probably a condition that what's preceding it should be independent of what comes next

Comment: The best piece of advice I can possibly give anyone is that they should never be reading *about* dashes. They should just be reading, period.

Comment: Looks like a sentence to me.

Comment: It looks fine to me. It is a sentence.