# How Would One Use A Semicolon (;)?

Tags: american-english, british-english, differences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one correctly use a semicolon?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-does-one-correctly-use-a-semicolon)

I'm wondering about the difference between just ending the sentence and starting a new one based on the same subject and using a semicolon to branch the two sentences together.

Can anyone help me on this one?