# Did she use a semicolon correctly?

Tags: punctuation

I was reading through random quotes and found this:

> What terrified me will terrify others; and I need only describe the spectre which had haunted my midnight pillow.

It's from Mary Shelley, in case you're curious.

I was wondering, though, if she uses the semicolon correctly. I've always been taught not to put them before any transition words and told that if you can replace one with a comma that you've used it wrong.

Maybe my idea of commas and periods is wrong? I'm not sure. Either way, it's been on my mind and this seems like a good place to ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one correctly use a semicolon?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-does-one-correctly-use-a-semicolon)

Comment: How could Mary Shelley possibly be "wrong", given that punctuation is a matter of style, convention, and personal choice, and she a noted literary luminary?

Comment: Keep in mind that punctuation usage and "norms"  change over time; and Mary Shelley's usage can't fairly be "held up" to some practice of today that can allegedly be called correct or incorrect.

Comment: `that you've used it wrong` - according to who? There is no central authority for the English language, and it changes over time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of finding out is to exchange the two halves of the sentence and see if it still makes sense:

> I need only describe the spectre which had haunted my midnight pillow; and what terrified me will terrify others.

As can be seen, the sentence still makes perfect sense, and so the use of a semicolon is appropriate.

Comment: One sect of the semicolon religion holds that any conjunction should be dropped following a semicolon.  If there's a conjunction a comma should be used.

Comment: Other sects hold that it is an abomination and should not be used at all. I'll defer to Mrs Shelley.

Comment: Those are the heretics.

Comment: @HotLicks Hyper-Calvinists, I'd say.

Comment: Redcoats.  The main religion is the Semicolonials.